# Clientside password hashing

Tags: security, hash, passwords

A friend of mine and me are having a discussion about whether we should pre-hash the passwords of the users of our webapp before sending it to our servers.

I know that there are multiple questions that already handle this topic but they're all about transferring it securely to the server. Our idea is not about the transfer security (we use SSL) we want to hash clientside to prevent that the "real" passwords reach our server.

The idea came as Twitter announced their bug that caused passwords to be printed to a logfile in cleartext.

We are currently discussing about whether this concept makes sense or not and how it affects the security of a password (in terms of Bruteforce) if we would hash it with SHA512.

**TL;DR:**

We want to hash passwords clientside to prevent our servers from getting them in cleartext (we use SSL for transfer).

Does this make any sense?
What algorithm would be best to use for hashing?

The hashed passwords would then serverside be hashed again with bCrypt.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely good practice for exactly the reasons you discuss. You should avoid ever sending the raw password to the server. Passwords should be salted and stretched as close to the user as possible. For a full discussion of how to implement this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31386549/97337.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31726272/407722.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It 100% makes sense: in fact, the concept has been proposed by a number of people, but the difficulty is in implementing correctly.  There are a number of pitfalls if you do it wrong, the most direct one is being vulnerable to "pass-the-hash" as @swa66 describes.  To prevent that, you need to hash on both sides.  The client-side hash should be slow (bcrypt, scrypt, argon2, or pbkdf2) whereas the server side hash should be fast (sha256).

**EDIT**: A number of people have down-voted this without understanding how this works, so I now include the basic details here (previously I only linked to how this works).  The idea is to apply a slow hash such as bcrypt on the client side, and then a fast hash such as SHA256 on the server side.  The fast hash is required to prevent pass-the-hash attacks.  In the event of the database leak, an attacker either hash to invert the fast hash (impossible -- violates the one-way property of a cryptographic hash function), or brute force the preimage to the fast hash (impossible -- the size is the length of the output from the slow hash, for example 184-bits for bcrypt), or brute force the combination of the slow hash and the fast hash -- which puts the attacker back at the same position as if the entire computation had happened server side.  So we have not reduced the security of password attacks in the event of a database leak by shifting the heavy computation to the client side.

I've surveyed a number of proposals like this in [Method to protect passwords in databases for web applications](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/387.pdf).  Additionally, I analyse the pros and cons and identify weaknesses that have not been identified before (account enumeration), and propose a unique way of doing this securely.  The research is built off a number of sources, including:

- [Secure authentication: partial client-side key stretching… please review/criticize my idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43023/secure-authentication-partial-client-side-key-stretching-please-review-criti)
- [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846) -- see section on Client Side Hashing
- [Client side password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23006/client-side-password-hashing/23012)
- [Discussion from various authors on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7626587) -- see comments from oleganza, mschuster91, crusso, etc...

You cite the Twitter example, and GitHub did similarly.  When I wrote the paper above, the most prominent example for preventing a server from seeing the clear text passwords was Heartbleed, which I comment on in the paper (bottom of Section 1.3).

There has been subsequent follow up research by others identifying similar ideas -- [Example: Client-Plus-Server Password Hashing as a Potential Way to Improve Security Against Brute Force Attacks without Overloading the Server](http://ithare.com/client-plus-server-password-hashing-as-a-potential-way-to-improve-security-against-brute-force-attacks-without-overloading-server/).  No one person deserves all the credit, but the main takeaway is yes it is a good idea if you do it securely, but you really need to understand the risks (it is easy to do insecurely if you have not read the research).

Comment: Thanks for posting your research document. That was exactly what I've been looking for! Very informative. Seems strange but I loved reading it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MysteriousPerson Thanks.  I've updated this post to include direct links to other online sources that my research is built upon.

Comment: Show one world-renowned expert who recommends this. Till then: BAD IDEA.
E.g.: how would you salt the hash on the client side ? It's under the attacker's control. So you'll need a challenge-response there. If not: your slow hash of the password can be attacked by a rainbow table and essentially adds next to nothing.
E.g.: you remove the slow hash on the server and replace it with a fast one: impact: you're vulenrable to bruteforcing as the "hash is the password" didn't expand the search domain (it's still the same size as the dictionary of possible inputs was) you're now off worse ...

Comment: @swa66 I think [Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) counts as a world-renowned expert.  And while I am not going to claim to be a world-renowned expert, I do have a [pretty solid track record in cryptography](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Scott+Contini&btnG=).  How to salt on the client side?  Read my paper and you will see how it's done -- salt comes from the server.  Happy for you to write up your attacks more formally, because your short description doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TheGreatContini What I can think of is, that the server itself may be vulnerable to Bruteforcing attacks, as the server-side hash is a relatively fast one. I don't need to compute the output of the PPF. I can just send valid hashes to the server until I have the right one. Which doesn't give me the user password but allows me to get access to the users account. It's like trying to bruteforce a very securely chosen password on a site that hashes it with a fast hash. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm an absolute beginner in this case.

Comment: @MysteriousPerson If that were possible, then hashing would be broken in general. But it is not possible -- the largest brute force attack ever completed, a massively distributed effort, was [64-bits](https://www.distributed.net/RC5) to my knowledge. PPF outputs are *at least* 128-bit in practice (typically longer) -- which is 2^64 times harder, well beyond anything that can be computed in the lifetime of the universe. The risk is brute forcing passwords, not hashes, and that's why we do the PPF on the password.

Comment: As I thought of the implementation. I noticed that most websites let their users at account creation know whether the username is taken or not in form of a failure message or success. Woudln't this break the whole database discovery protection that is built around the salt?

Comment: @MysteriousPerson you are correct that nearly all websites that allow self registration are vulnerable to account enumeration on the signup page.  In that case, a simpler protocol can apply.

Comment: Server-side hashing should not be fast. The reason of doing bcrypt in the first place is to slowdown de-hashing when the database got leaked. You cannot offload bcrpyting.

Comment: @КонстантинВан please read the paper I linked to so you have an understanding of how we can shift the heavy computation to the client side while still maintaining security in the event of a password leak.  Or else read any of the other links I provided.  The concept is really not that difficult: that's why it has been re-invented 30+ times over.  My contribution is analysis more than anything else.

Comment: @TheGreatContini I read [the §4](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/387.pdf). It says that the client sends the slow-hashed (“_PPF_'d”) and the server fast-hashes (“SHA”) it to store in the database. ― What I'm pointing out is ― In case of database leaking, a cracker can de-hash the leaked **fast**-hashes and submit the de-hashed, pretending it's the slow-hashed, to the server to auth. The “clientside-hash-becoming-a-plain-password” problem. Could you please tell me what I've misread?

Comment: @КонстантинВан "de-hash" the leaked fast-hash means breaking the one-way property of the hash function, which is not possible by the definition of [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).  Nobody has ever been able to invert any of the SHA algorithms.  Unless you are thinking about brute forcing it, but the size of the value to brute force is the output size of the slow hash.  For example, in the bcrypt case it is 184-bits.  That is way too large to brute force -- largest effort ever carried out was 2^64 (for rc6-64) by distributed net.

Comment: Note also @КонстантинВан that MysteriousPerson suggested the same thing in the comments above, and I responded to him.  To make the point more clear, I have now updated the original answer to why that attack does not make the design more vulnerable.  Please be aware that a number of people, including famous cryptographers like Thomas Pornin, have also said the same thing and my original answer links to their discussions.  I agree that my answer should have had those details here rather than linking elsewhere, so that's why I updated the answer.

Comment: Why are you talking about “the bcrypt case?” What I am saying is that (Ⅰ) the cracker does not need to decrypt the client-side bcrypted (Your bcrypting is completely meaningless to the cracker, since once he reverts the server-side works, the server will accept him.) but the server-side SHA'd. (Ⅱ) Then what's the point of doing bcrypt instead of SHA when SHA is secure enough not to be decrypted by definition, as you said?

Comment: Cryptologically speaking, your design is nothing more secure than the client doing nothing and the server using SHA. Why do you think the dominant number of servers all around the world are still doing heavy, slow hashing instead of SHA? Because they are ignorant that they don't even know SHA is unidirectional?

Comment: Your design lacks the way for the server to judge whether the client has _really_ done bcrypt or it's just the decryption, which the cracker sends to the server to sign in, of a SHA'd cipher from the leaked database.

Comment: @КонстантинВан First, don't call it my design -- many people have come up with this concept.  Second, understand the purpose of the slow hash function.  SHA by itself does not work for passwords because passwords tend to be small, and human memorisable, which means you can crack them using a dictionary and a tool like hashcat provided that you fire enough computing power at it.  The same concept does not work if the input is large and random looking.   And that's exactly the point of the slow function such as bcrypt: the output is large and random looking.

Comment: Interesting research! I'd never heard about slow-client-side + fast-server-side. The last article explains it well.

Comment: After finishing that article, I would point out the author does suggest that even if the client-side hash is slower, the server-side hash should not be fast and mentions against SHA-256 as an example.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**!

Rule one in cryptography: do not invent it yourself, you'll make horrible mistakes.

It's not against you personally, by far not: even top notch experts make mistakes when designing with great care new systems. That's why they peer-review each-other's work multiple times before anything become a standard. Many proposals for such standards by such experts get redrawn due to problems detected during such a peer-review. So why can't the rest of us mere mortals design: there's nobody good enough to do the peer-review as the experts will not touch it.

**Hashing the password client side**

Hashing client side is really bad as the hash becomes the password, and now you store it on the server in the clear.

**How to do passwords**

1. Only store hashed passwords (implied: send the password to the server, just do not store it)
2. use a salt and store it with the password (unencrypted). The salt is essentially a random string that you concatenate to the pasword before you hash it (to store it , and to verify it)
3. Use a SLOW hash. Using a fast hash is a common and fatal mistake, even when using salts. Most hash functions people know like SHA-256, SHA-3 etc. are fast hashes and completely unsuitable for hashing short, predictable items like passwords as they can be reversed in a surprising short time.

   How slow: as slow as you can afford. Examples of slow hashes:
   bcrypt, PBKDF-2 (which is essentially a high number of rounds of a
   fast hash to make it slow)

There are -depending on your programming environment- pre-made routines, use them!

Ref:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-makes-a-hash-function-good-for-password-hashing
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59797/authorities-on-password-hashing-best-practice

Comment: While this is true for many (most, even) use-cases, sometimes client-side password hashing *may* in fact make sense. Also why would the server then store the hashed password in the clear (without hashing it once again)? Obviously, it should not, but that doesn't mean one should never hash passwords on the client. It's just a special case that may mitigate threats that aren't normally relevant for most applications - but *are* for some.

Comment: Thans for the hint! I don't want to create my own way of storing the passwords securely. I want to prevent that the passwords will be sent in cleartext to the server (If I don't have them in plaintext its much less dangerous in case of a bug that would cause passwords to be printed in cleartext somewhere, in that case only the pre-hashed passwords would show up). And as mentioned: The pre-hashed passwords would be hashed again server-side.

Comment: Indeed, there are a number of proposals on the web on how to do this including at least 5 examples that explicitly state that you need to hash on both sides to prevent the pass-the-hash attack.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. This puts the burden of heavy computation like argon2 on the server, leaving yourself open to CPU attack

Answer (score 1):

While @swa66 outlined how to manage passwords securely, let me note that there *is* a valid scenario where you can consider client-side password hashing, so don't just blindly follow "best practice", try and understand it first.

Let's say I have a standard web application that stores data from users. In my threat model, I don't even want my own users to have to trust me, or in other words, I want my users' data to be secure even in case of a full compromise of my servers. Therefore, I let them choose a password, and encrypt their data on the client, before sending it to the application. They can retrieve their encrypted data with their user id. Well, that doesn't sound very secure, I can just download anybody's encrypted data and run offline attacks against it. So let's have them access their encrypted data with their password (I don't want them to have to remember two different passwords). But that's not good, because I have their password then to decrypt their data. So one simple solution is to encrypt their data with their password, and send it to the server along with their hashed password, which as it's correctly noted in the answer *is* the new password as far as the server is concerned (so the server should store it hashed once again and so on). However, the server has no way to decrypt client data, because it never has the original password, yet only the valid person can download even their encrypted stuff, and they only have to remember one password. (Note that this is a very much simplified model, in reality, much more is needed, like for example a proper key derivation function, not just plain hashes, but that's another, much longer story.)

Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying you should normally be hashing passwords on the client - no, the other answer is the correct one in that regard. I just wanted to show that there *is* at least one use-case where client-side password hashing is a valid option. See well-known password managers, some work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to hash also on the client side in addition to server side hashing. However in contrast to server side hashing which protects the server, client side hashing is something that protects the user and not the server. The whole point of client side hashing is that many users reuse their passwords on other websites so client side hashing can help protecting those passwords. So client side hashing can never replace server side hashing but it makes sense to implement it additionally to your server side hashing. There are at least few points that I think make client side hasing useful:

- both you and your users can sleep better knowing that you can't leak their plaintext passwords because you never receive them
- in case a bad guy gets a full control of your server he will not receive plaintext passwords while users are logging in
- in case you hire some external companies to manage your server they also won't see plaintext passwords
- if your client app is a mobile app then it makes even more sense as in such case a hacker won't be able to remove client side hashing even if he gets a full control of your server (and for web app you probably would notice faster that someone hacked you if he removed client side hashing from your web app)
- you will never accidentally log plaintext passwords in log files

Now the question is how to implement client side hashing? Assuming that this client side hashing is something that you just add as an addition for user's safety (and not server's safety) and you treat it as something completely separate from the server side hashing then the simplest thing that people propose you can do is just to make a hash with constant domain string as proposed in https://medium.com/@harwoeck/password-and-credential-management-in-2018-56f43669d588 I think this already adds some benefit in terms of protecting the user's password in case he reused it on other websites especially if you use a slow hashing algorithm. However you could easily improve it by additionally using user's username/email as his client side pseudo salt as proposed in "Password authentication for web & mobile apps" book from https://dchest.com/authbook/ This would still be very easy to implement as it would not require changes on the server side because you never need to store this pseudo client side salt as user needs to enter his username/email on the login screen/page anyway and it adds the benefit of having each client side hash different for users with the same passwords. Author of this book suggests using some slow hashing functions for client side hashing so that it's harder to brute force them. To me it seems that this is a quite good and simple way to implement client side hashing as it does not require to request any salts for client side hashing from the server during the login. So in summary something like slowhash(domain_string+user_email+user_password) on the client side looks like a good and simple solution to me. I do not see any downsides of doing it this way if you still have a proper server side hashing with randomly generated salt stored in your database on your server. Keep in mind that modern hardware can calculate hashes like SHA512 very fast. For example according to some benchmarks that I just checked RTX4090 calculated them with speed 7409.5 MH/s - 7409 millions of SHA512 per second (!) so that's why using a different slower hashing methods would be safer.