SQL Server stored procedure adding values to table run successful, but no result show in the table
I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server to add new student record to Student table. I have grant permission to one of the roles I created that is "DBAdmins". I have also login as "DBAdmins" and run the stored procedure successfully, it returns 1 row affected.
But when I select * from student table, it has nothing in the table. Here is the stored procedure I created and the execute command run from DBAdmins.
I have tried run the execute command, try "INSERT INTO" command, but nothing is working. There is no result in the student table.
Stored procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddNewStudent
    @StudentID VARCHAR(6),
    @TempPassword VARCHAR(100),
    @Name VARCHAR(100),
    @Phone VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY PasswordEncryptionKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE AISServerCert;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Student (ID, SystemPwd, Name, Phone)
    VALUES (@StudentID, 
            EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('PasswordEncryptionKey'), @TempPassword),
            @Name, @Phone);

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY PasswordEncryptionKey;
END;

Execute command:
EXEC dbo.AddNewStudent
    @StudentID = 'ST1001',
    @TempPassword = 'TP0001@1234',
    @Name = 'John Doe',
    @Phone = '012-2148759';


I dunno what sqlhelper is, but i don't see anything particularily wrong with your query, so i'm guessing: 1) It rolls back transactions 2) It swallows errors. What happens if you run it in sql server management studio or some other "mainstream" client

Please add the sql statement you are using to check, i.e. the before and after select statement

On  side note: encrypting the password using reversible encryption is wrong, and doing that server-side is doubly wrong. Passwords should be salted-and-hashed using a one way hash function on the client, then passed to the server.

@Charlieface If that was the case, then the leaked databases with the salted hashes stored on the server would have been immediately usable as passwords. Fortunately they are not, you have to reverse the stolen hash into a password first, because what you have to send to the server is the password, not the hash.

@GSerg Hash != symmetric encryption. A hash is a one way function which is not reversible, encryption is reversible. Noone "reverses the stolen hash into a password", they brute-force (or other method) to find a password with amatching hash, usually the same password but not necessarily. No, what you send to the server should not be the password itself. The server doesn't need to know the password, it just needs to know the hash. Even better: use a proper handshake protocol where even the hash is not transferred except when first creating it.

@Charlieface I know the difference, and I specifically mentioned the need to reverse the hash into a password as a relevant measure of protection, because there is supposed to be no easy way to do that. What you are saying is that the server is presented with a ready hash, which it isn't. The server doesn't store the password, but it's presented with one for both creating an account and authentication. That password is delivered over a secure channel such as HTTPS, and if you don't trust your HTTPS then all other measures are useless too.

@GSerg I guess it's all a matter of opinion. There seems to be plenty of discussion of client vs server-side hashing (or both even) eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/53370008/14868997 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716654/14868997 Note that HTTPS really isn't as secure as you might think (eg firewall/AV software which do MITM), and putting clear-text passwords in an HTTPS channel seems to be a bad idea. Sending nonces for the client-side to hash with the password would also seem prudent, this can prevent replay attacks.
